# Deriving a matrix values from another 2 matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose you have Matrix A.

[image: 5x3 A matrix]

Suppose also that we have Matrix C

[image: 5x3 C Matrix]

***If we have A = B x C   and we want to find out the B matrix values which I believe should be 3x3 (Correct me if I am wrong)***

Do we need to use matrix inversion here? I did not use algebra since many years.

I do not have a code yet but if someone can provide a snippet that will be great.

This is a problem that I have in image processing where the A , C hold RGB values.

The submitted matrices are just for illustration.

I am trying to solve this problem using Python numpy 
I hope that someone can help with it.

Comment: You are wrong. If A = B.C then dimensionwise (5,3) = (x,y)(5,3). This would mean B must have shape (5, 5).

Comment: you are right 5x5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix should be 5x5. As we are dealing with non-square matrices, you could use the generalized inverse of C to obtain B:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)

A = np.random.randint(0,9,(5,3))
C = np.random.randint(0,9,(5,3))

B = np.matmul(A,np.linalg.pinv(C))

print B
```

Comment: Note that `C` is a rank deficient matrix so for this example reconstructing `A` with `B x C` will not give the same results.  However, this is the correct procedure for calculating what is required.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you . Is there anyway or any possibility that we can reduce B to 3x3 and we still get the right results?

Comment: No, due to the way matrix multiplication works, the number of columns of B should correspond to the number of rows of C and the number of rows of B should correspond to the number of rows of A

Comment: Don't use pinv for linear equation sets unless you really need to use the pseudoinverse as a standalone matrix. Either use `np.linalg.solve` for full rank or use `lstsq` for under/over determined cases.

Answer (score 0):

Building on percusse's comment, you can do this with [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).  However, this assumes that we are performing matrix left division but the situation is your question is for right division.

Using the fact that you are solving for B with `B = A / C`, `lstsq` solves problems of the type `A \ C`.  To convert this into a form for `lstsq`, we can convert it into the latter problem by:

```
B = A / C = (C' \ A')'
```

The `'` operator is the transpose.  The above is found by linear algebra rules.  Specifically, perform two transposes: `((A / C)')'` where transposing a matrix twice is simply the result of itself.  Also, knowing that `(AC)'` is equal to `C'A'` and for a matrix, the inverse of the transpose is equal to the transpose of the inverse you should get the above relationship.

Therefore:

```
B = numpy.linalg.lstsq(C.T, A.T)[0].T
```

The output of `lstsq` is a tuple where the first element is the actual solution.

Take note that for your particular example, `C` is a rank-deficient matrix so you won't be able to reconstruct `A` properly from `B` and `C`.

Comment: Thank you. All of this question was in order to understand how to get CCM - Color Correction Matrix as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng  - Which is 3x3 matrix.. However I am too lost now :-)  you can see my question also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157342/measure-color-accuracy-python-and-opencv